# Selecting multiple with table alias and typed query

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I needed to join the same table twice so have seen in docs that I can use table alias but I am having some difficulty selecting the joined tables..

This is what I tried:

```cs
var q = _AutoQuery.CreateDevXQuery(request, base.Request.GetRequestParams(), base.Request);
q.LeftJoin<WritingAssignment, Blog>((w, b) => w.WriterSuggestBlog == b.Id, Db.TableAlias("b1"));
q.LeftJoin<WritingAssignment, Blog>((w, b) => w.ApprovedBlog == b.Id, Db.TableAlias("b2"));

q.Select<WritingAssignment, WriterProfile, Blog>((wa, wp, b) => new
{
    WritingAssignment = wa,
    WriterProfile = wp,
    SuggestedBlog = Sql.TableAlias(b, "b1"),
    AcceptedBlog = Sql.TableAlias(b, "b2")
});

var values = Db.Select<Tuple<WritingAssignment, WriterProfile, Blog, Blog>>(q);
```

The `WritingAssignment` and `WriterProfile` come through fine but the two blog value are coming through with just default property values. The docs only show example of it working with single column.  What is the way to reference the entire table with a table alias?

I got it working with this select:

```cs
q.Select("writing_assignment.*, 0 EOT, writer_profile.*, 0 EOT, b1.*, 0 EOT, b2.*");
```

But I feel like I should be able to get it working with `Sql.TableAlias`.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added support for this syntax in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/1ba40ef4b77d9ae792a268f1683c51960d4476d6) where your initial syntax should work as expected:

```
q.Select<WritingAssignment, WriterProfile, Blog>((wa, wp, b) => new
{
    WritingAssignment = wa,
    WriterProfile = wp,
    SuggestedBlog = Sql.TableAlias(b, "b1"),
    AcceptedBlog = Sql.TableAlias(b, "b2")
});

var values = Db.Select<Tuple<WritingAssignment, WriterProfile, Blog, Blog>>(q);
```

By default if no `EOT` delimiter is set, selecting multiple tables in a Tuple will split based on the model field count, but whenever the selected list of fields doesn't match Model definition you can insert explicit table delimiters with `Sql.EOT`, e.g:

```
q.Select<WritingAssignment, WriterProfile, Blog>((wa, wp, b) => new
{
    Id = wa.Id,
    Name = wa.Name,
    t1 = Sql.EOT,
    WriterProfile = wp,
    t2 = Sql.EOT,
    SuggestedBlog = Sql.TableAlias(b, "b1"),
    t3 = Sql.EOT,
    AcceptedBlog = Sql.TableAlias(b, "b2")
});

var values = Db.Select<Tuple<WritingAssignment, WriterProfile, Blog, Blog>>(q);
```

This change is available from v5.11.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).